# How do i run mongoose methods on array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My goal is to run mongoose method on an array of objects. For example

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    time: { type: Number, default: 24 }
});

ItemSchema.methods.minus2 = function() {
    this.time -= 2;
    this.save();
}
```

Api method

```
app.get('/allItems', function(req, res) {
    Item.find({}, function(err, items) {
      // I want to run items.calculateTime(); but it is not possible.
      // How would I run calculateTime function on the array of objects?
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your overall objective? Do you want to include a computed field in your results? What is your MongoDB server version?

Comment: I want to update the time field. Server version is 3.0.6

Comment: The time field might change. So that's why I need to check. I feel like this way is not efficient, but I can't think of any solution, to update the time field.

Comment: Should I use `pre` method on my schema?

Comment: I think you might want to use the `aggregate()` function instead of `find()` for the `GET` allItems API  where you can use the available [arithmetic operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/) to do the check and computations.

Comment: Is this the only option? or there are others?